# flex-grow max value or shrink margin for space between elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm building a navigation based on two lists on same line. All of the items in the two lists should have spacing between each other, but `25px` at most.

**The problem with flex-grow:**
If I use flex-grow, the elements get bigger than their own width + 25px because there's enough space available.

**The problem with margin-right:**
If the container is smaller, the margin-right of 25px is not reduced, then the items will break lines instead of shrinking their margins.

Possible solution:
Using a div between each element, giving it `flex-grow:1` and `max-width:25px`.

Is there another way without additional html?

Here's a codepen showing the problem:

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul,
.container,
.container2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container,
.container2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

.container ul.first {
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* this works, but each element should only grow by 25px */
}

.container ul.first,
.container2 ul.first {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.container2 ul.first li {
  margin-right: 25px;
  /* this works, but should be reduced if not enough space */
}
```

```html
<h2>Example 1: flex-grow on li</h2>
<p>Problem: the items get too big, should be max 25px spacing</p>
<div class=container>
  <ul class=first>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>fourth</li>
    <li>fifth</li>
    <li>sixth</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class=second>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<h2>Example 2: margin-right on li</h2>
<p>Problem: the spacing is not reduced on smaller containers</p>
<div class=container2>
  <ul class=first>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>fourth</li>
    <li>fifth</li>
    <li>sixth</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class=second>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do we know number of items in each list?
Do we know the max-width of list?

Comment: @UtsavPatel unfortunately no, the item length is dynamic (also because of multi languages) and the max-width of the list also, because there are 2 lists in the same row

Comment: Then I think this cannot be worked around without having additional div as you mentioned in the post.

Comment: Here's an attempt using CSS grid. Is this what you're talking about? https://jsfiddle.net/y7nkcL4b/

Comment: @Michael_B is there a way to make the gaps shrink when container is smaller?

Answer (score 0):

one idea is to consider the use of pseudo element and `display:contents`

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul{
  display: inline-flex;
  max-width:100%;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}


.container ul.first{
  margin-right: 30px;
  max-width:calc(100% - 30px);
}

ul li:not(:last-child) {
  display:contents;
}
ul li:not(:last-child)::after {
   content:"";
   width:25px;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <ul class=first>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>fourth</li>
    <li>fifth</li>
    <li>sixth</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class=second>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: this is awesome, thank you! Unfortunately, it only really runs on chrome, doesn't work on safari and not at all on IE11 (https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents) :( any ideas how to tweak this to make it run crossbrowser?